# TYPO3 HMENU browse previous button doesn't show for page one level above

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I added a browse navigation with the following TypoScript code to my site.

```
lib.nextprevious = COA
lib.nextprevious {
    wrap = <div class="turn">|</div>
    # prev
    1 = HMENU
    1.special = browse
    1.special {
        items = prev |
        items.prevnextToSection = 1
        prev.fields.title = {$config.terms.previousPage}
        prev.fields.nav_title = {$config.terms.previousPage}
    }
    1.1 = TMENU
    1.1.wrap = <span class="prev">|</span>

    # next
    2 < .1
    2.special {
        items = | next
        next.fields.title = {$config.terms.nextPage}
        next.fields.nav_title = {$config.terms.nextPage}
    }
    2.1.wrap = <span class="next">|</span>
}
```

Everything works fine, except on two sites, which are before and after a page with no subpages. The next-link skips this page one level above and the previous-link doesn't even show.

- Home

  - Nuts (link to walnut)

    - Walnut
    - Peanut
  - Fruits (link to apple)

    - Apple
    - Pear <- **Next link to tomato**
  - About us
  - Vegetables (link to tomato)

    - Tomato <- **Previous doesn't show up on this page**
    - Aubergine

Tomato should go to 'About us' because Vegetables is just a link to tomato. Next should go to About us.

Can someone help me in this case?

Comment: there is something strange: the `next`link from `pear` to `tomato`. I would expect `next`/`prev` to work only in the current siblings of a page. no jump to another level, no jump to other pages on the same level but with other parent. And as the shortcuts are from higher level to sublevel the sublevel is shown and current page, so no link from `Vegetables` to `Fruits` (and of course no link to a subpage of `Fruits`).

Comment: The parent pages (except About us) are symlinks to the first child page, because the parent has no content. It can jump between childs from different parents because i set the option `items.prevnextToSection = 1`. Although when a page has no children, it seemingly doesnt work. This is weird because the navigation from `Walnut` to to Pear works perfect, but then the described problem happens.